# showing fetched data on html

Tags: php, html, json, fetch

I'm trying to display a data I fetched on a html file. I want the ***json*** be shown where I put **HERE** but I'dont have any idea of how

```
<script defer>
fetch("http://localhost:8080/bot/guilds")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then((json) => {
        document.getElementById("servers").innerHTML = json
    })
</script>
<div class="statistics">
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card statistic" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-title" style="font-size: 50px !important;line-height: 15px !important;letter-spacing: -0.06em !important;font-weight: bold !important;">HERE</h1>
                <p style="font-weight: bold !important;font-size: 20px !important;">servers</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are trying to set an HTML value to JSON?

Comment: Do you wish to simply display the JSON data as `key=value` pairs? How complex is the JSON? How many levels are there in the JSON? So far there is too little to know what the intention is

Comment: Spend a moment in the help and you will find out how to copy/paste code into a question and properly format it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is json_encode()

```
<script>
      var js_sample = <?php echo json_encode($php_sample)?>;
<script>
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP needs at all. This will generate the JSON content perhaps but not help in displaying it

Comment: I mean, when you click that site, you get a number (2). And I want it to display that number

Comment: Your just need to give it pair of quote marks then it would be a string, then you user innerHTML to put it on the element.
`<script>
      var js_sample = '<?php echo json_encode($php_sample)?>';
      document.querySelector('p.card-title').innerHTML = js_sample;
<script>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. The only part that's wrong is that the `json` variable is still an Object. You are probably looking for `JSON.stringify()` to display it as a string.

See the corrected code under here.

```
<script defer>
fetch("http://localhost:8080/bot/guilds")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then((json) => {
        document.getElementById("servers").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json)
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Also, there is no element `#servers` in the code in the question – the paragraph with the class `.card-title` needs a matching ID attribute for the JavaScript to ever find it.

Comment: I solved that but I still don't have any idea of putting the json value on where I put **HERE**

Answer (score 0):

You try to display json data in a place that doesn't exist, that's the main issue here. If you want to show it in place of 'HERE' label, use this selector:

`document.querySelector('p.card-title').innerHTML = json`

Also, json is an object, so you will want to change it to a string to display nicely:

`document.querySelector('p.card-title').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json)`

That should work.

- And one more thing, your p.card-title tag is opened with P tag and closed with H1 tag, change that closing H1 to P as well.

Comment: And how to give that **HERE** a separated name?

Comment: Well, elements can be identified by ID or CLASS. If you want to give it a separate name, place another tag within the p.card-title that will be a placeholder for that data, and then set its innerHTML to your JSON.

Example:
`<p class="card-title" style="font-size: 50px !important;line-height: 15px !important;letter-spacing: -0.06em !important;font-weight: bold !important;"><span class="json-result">HERE</span></p>`

`document.querySelector('span.json-result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who helped ^^ I used a module (cors) and it worked

Comment: By all meas provide an answer to your own question if it is better than any other. But it really should be an answer to the question. This is not an answer